# Declaring SMALL_RECT = {}, does not resize the console window

Tags: c++, windows, c++17, windows-console

I am just playing around with simple console applications in C++.

I am trying to resize the console window, and it works fine. First I resize the actual window, then the buffer and all is fine, but once I tried to compress the code, the window no longer resizes. It is really not that important. I am just generally wondering as most suggestions that I looked at declare the `SMALL_RECT` that way.

P.S I am using TDM-GCC 64 and Eclipse with std=c++17

This works and the window is resized properly

```
void SetCMDSizeAndTitle(short width, short height, string title) {
    COORD coord = { width, height };
    SMALL_RECT rect;

     rect.Top = 0;
     rect.Left = 0;
     rect.Bottom = height - 1;
     rect.Right = width - 1;

    SetConsoleTitle(TEXT(title.c_str()));

    SetConsoleWindowInfo(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), TRUE, &rect);
    SetConsoleScreenBufferSize(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), coord);
}
```

However this does not work, the window remains the default size

```
void SetCMDSizeAndTitle(short width, short height, string title) {
    COORD coord = { width, height };

    SMALL_RECT rect = { 0, 0, height - 1, width -1 };

    SetConsoleTitle(TEXT(title.c_str()));

    SetConsoleWindowInfo(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), TRUE, &rect);
    SetConsoleScreenBufferSize(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), coord);
}
```

This is not really that important. It is just nicer when there is less lines of code, and I am just generally curious why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it is not working is because according to the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686311(v=vs.85).aspx) the variables are not in the order you assume.  The MSDN defined the struct as

```
typedef struct _SMALL_RECT {
  SHORT Left;
  SHORT Top;
  SHORT Right;
  SHORT Bottom;
}
```

Which means you need to follow that order in the initialization list.  That means you should have

```
SMALL_RECT rect = {0, 0, width -1, height - 1};
//                 L  T         R           B
```

Comment: @SteelShot No problem.  Glad to help.